# Gnome Tracker does not seem to work

Tags: gnome, tracker

I have Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome Desktop - the one with "Search" popping out when you press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.

I checked if the tracker indexes my `.flac` files:

```
tracker3 info '/home/janbenes/Music/03. Spanish Tune.flac'
```

And yes, among the info there is for example:

```
'nfo:genre' = 'Progressive Rock'
```

So why does the Gnome search or search in file manager return *nothing* when I enter "progressive"? There must be something wrong or Gnome Tracker is not integrated with Gnome search?

I have these in my search-providers directory:

```
gnome-control-center-search-provider.ini  org.gnome.Calculator-search-provider.ini  org.gnome.Nautilus.search-provider.ini
gnome-terminal-search-provider.ini        org.gnome.Characters.search-provider.ini  seahorse-search-provider.ini
is-search-provider.ini                    org.gnome.Gnote.search-provider.ini
```